# Swift Saving Videos to Camera Roll INCLUDING LIBRARY

Tags: swift, video, camera-roll

UPDATE:

Ok so I found a post explaining that if the content is appearing in the recents album, then they must be in the Library. They are just sorted by date. This is exactly the case for me. If I scroll back to when the original video was taken, my new copy will be there. The thing that doesn't make sense is images are saved unsorted, so they appear as the most recent item in the Library but videos are sorted. Why is that?

Either way, is it possible to strip/change the date on a video/image when saving to the camera roll to ensure they have the current datetime stamp? Perhaps I should post this as a new question...

---

This is really confusing me. When I save an image to the user's camera roll using **UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()**, the image will appear not only in the "recents" album in the "Photos" app, but will also appear under the "Library" tab in the photos app. However, when I save a ***video*** to the user's camera roll using **UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum()**, the video appears in the "recents" album in the "photos" app but NOT under the "Library" tab in the photos app.

Can anyone explain how to save a video and have it appear under the Library tab as well? Generally, that is the default tab that opens in the photos app when I look for recent images. In fact, while I was testing this functionality, I kept thinking it wasn't working even though it wasn't throwing any error. I kept checking the photos app and it wasn't there. It wasn't until I had the bright idea to check the specific album that I saw I had a ton of copies of the test video in there! :-)

Technically it's working, I just think this could possibly confuse the user should they rely on the "Library" in the photos app to find their saved video.

Any thoughts?

...Scotty